# bacbone.router.extend not working

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

Backbone.Router.extend is giving me the error: **"extend" cannot be used on 
undefined**
**Nodejs** and **express** is also used in this project.
but i have not mentioned anythin related to backbone in **app.js**
Below is my **index.html** and **main.js**.
 
I have a feeling, the jquery,underscore and backbone files may not be loading properly,due to which this error is happening
Kind of beginner in backbone.Any help is greatly appreciated

**index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
            <script src="javascripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="javascripts/json2.js"></script>
            <script src="javascripts/underscore-min.js"></script>
            <script src="javascripts/backbone-min.js"></script>
            <script src="javascripts/main.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>

            <h1>< title </h1> 
            <p>Welcome to  world of html</p>

         </body>
    </html>
```

**main.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var Theater = {
        Models: {},
        Collections: {},
        Views: {},
        Templates:{},
        Routers:{}
    }

    Theater.Models.Movie = Backbone.Model.extend({});


    Theater.Collections.Movies = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Theater.Models.Movie,
        url: "/json",
        initialize: function(){
            console.log("Movies initialize")
        }
    });


    Theater.Routers = Backbone.Router.extend({
        initialize:function(){  console.log("defaultRoute");},
        routes: {
            "": "defaultRoute" 
        },
        defaultRoute: function () {
            console.log("defaultRoute");
        }
    });

    console.log("gonna call approuter");
    var appRouter = new Theater.Routers();
    Backbone.history.start();

});
```

Comment: What is the version of Backbone you are using?

Comment: @suish: // Backbone.js 0.3.3

Answer (score 0):

> A large number of tiny tweaks and micro bugfixes, best viewed by looking at the commit diff. HTML5 pushState support, enabled by opting-in with: Backbone.history.start({pushState: true}). Controller was renamed to Router, for clarity. Collection#refresh was renamed to Collection#reset to emphasize its ability to both reset the collection with new models, as well as empty out the collection when used with no parameters.

Backbone change log of 0.5.0

http://backbonejs.org/

Backbone's `Router` was called `Controller` and renamed to `Router` when it got version 0.5

Simply replace your Backbone and Underscore files into newer version or use `Controller` instead. then your code should work.

I strongly recommend to update your Backbone file due to bugs which Backbone used to have.

Comment: i replace it with controller and it worked.... but as you suggested i took backbone.js from 'http://cdnjs.com/libraries/backbone.js/' and now it is showing an error related to bacbone-min.map.......... ANy suggeestion?

Comment: that's different story.map file itself is just sourceMapping file for the js which means it isn't be required to run the code.
but anyway, use minified version of it `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.2/backbone-min.js` then no more map file error.

Comment: now the map file error seems to be gone. but now an another error pointing to Backbone.Model.extend as undefined function has come out. Any idea???...

Comment: ok, now i updated the underscore file also. map file error seems to be gone. now an error pointing to to 'Backbone.history.start()' seems to have risen.......... WHY????????